# Reports in Ax2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ax

I am new to Axapta. Can you please guide the best to way to learn the repots in AX2012 
Any URL OR video should help..

Regards
shaik

Comment: Next time, use a search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AX2012 Create SSRS Report using Data Provides Classes

http://krishhdax.blogspot.in/2012/07/ax2012-create-ssrs-report-using-data.html

hope this helps.

Thanks